# Installing software on Jenkins? (Particularly RVM)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, jenkins, rvm

I am trying to get Jenkins set up to build a Rails project on an EC2 instance, but I am not really sure what all I need to do. I have set up users and required that you login before accessing Jenkins and linked it up to the GitHub repo with the project, but I can't figure out how to get ruby installed.

I would like to be able to install RVM, and then have the build script just run `bundle` and then `rake build` every time a new commit is pushed to the GitHub.

How do I get RVM all set up on Jenkins?

Answer (score 0):

Please install the plugin through the Jenkins admin interface.

[Jenkins RVM Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/RVM+Plugin)

After installation, restart jenkins.

Create a new job to build the project and go to the Configure page.

Here you would see the option to mention the RVM ruby version you need to use.